# How to return arrays from while PHP

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have one cycle while:

```
while ($userEquipments = mysql_fetch_array($getUserEquipments))
```

and in this cycle have one if with arrays:

```
if ($userEquipments['cloth_id'] == $clothes['id'] && $userEquipments['cloth_is_used'] == 1)
            $isUsed = array('cloth_type' => $clothes['type_cloth'], 'cloth_name' => $clothes['name'], 'cloth_image' => $clothes['image']);
```

My question is how to return all information in this arrays?

Comment: I would use your SQL-statement to select certain rows, not use php to see which results you want.  Use a where-statement in you sql.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your array outside your while, this way you can access it outside the loop.

Try this:

```
$isUsed[];

while ($userEquipments = mysql_fetch_array($getUserEquipments))
{
    if ($userEquipments['cloth_id'] == $clothes['id'] && $userEquipments['cloth_is_used'] == 1)
    {
        $isUsed['cloth_type'] =  $clothes['type_cloth'];
        $isUsed['cloth_name'] =  $clothes['name'];
        ...
        break;
    }
}

// Print the array
print_r($isUsed);
```